# Allowing viewers to run a script in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a document that is shared with multiple people, all of which are only viewers.

Is there any way to allow players to run that script without giving them access to edit the file or change anything within the document?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: what does your script actually do ?

Comment: It is basically like a game. You have an inventory, and a cash amount. I am trying to keep it so that I am the only one who can edit it. I'm trying to allow players to click a "buy" button/option to allow them to add something to their inventory if they have the cash without my need for editing and on their own. 
I have the script worked out but cannot figure out how to make it so that others can use the script without giving them edit access.

Comment: Allow them to edit, but [protect the sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656)... and hope they won't think of editing the script itself.

Comment: You could create a Form and let users buy stuff through that https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms. Or you could use Apps Script to create a web app. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a web app using the script that you've already written.

Step 1) add the following lines of code to your existing code.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Use Case Name')
      .addItem('Start Use Case', 'NameOfFunctionThatShouldBeCalledFirst')
      .addToUi();
}
```

What the above lines of code does is it provides a way for the user to run the code without touching any cell.

Step 2) Publish and deploy your script as a web app. Follow the steps given [here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

**Note:** Select **"Me (yourEmailId@email.com)"** for the option **"Execute the app as:"**.

Also **Note:** Select anything as per your requirement **except "Only Myself"** for the option **"Who has access to the app:"**

Step 3) Share the sheet with whoever you have to, giving them only view rights.

What the entire process mentioned above does is, it enables you to restrict access (in terms of editing or making changes to the document) to the document by anyone else except you while helping you achieve what you want to.

Hope it works. Feel free to ask anything if you get stuck deploying the use case.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there a place you suggest as a tutorial for this? I understand how to put it into a web app and deploy, but do not understand the doGet/doPost. As I am fairly new and inexperienced, but was able to make what I wanted for my Google Sheets in Google Scripts and do not fully understand how to implement this by using the Web App.